# UI Testing is not supported on “My Mac” because it is running OS X 10.10.5 and UI Testing requires OS X 10.11 or later

Tags: xcode, macos, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I added UI testing to an existing OS X application and I'm now receiving the following error:
`UI Testing is not supported on “My Mac” because it is running OS X 10.10.5 and UI Testing requires OS X 10.11 or later.`

I followed this guide to add it:
http://savvyapps.com/blog/how-to-implement-ui-testing-in-an-existing-ios-app

`File → New → Target and click Test under the OS X template categories, and select OS X UI Testing Bundle`

This seems odd that I would have to upgrade my OS to the Gold Master copy when I'm just running XCode 7.  Should I downgrade to XCode 6? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apple's [WWDC15 video on UI Testing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/) at about 4:00 they show a slide which states that UI Testing depends on new OS features--OS X 10.11 is required.

It appears to be related to accessibility and privacy protection. You have to allow Accessibility to control your computer to get it to work. Accessibility is a key dependency for the new UI testing framework.

UI Testing is much better if you're able to do UI recording. According to Apple's [Xcode overview page](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RecordingUITests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH75-SW1):

Recording UI tests requires:

- A UI test target for your project
- Accessibility information for your UI elements
- OS X v10.11 or greater
- iOS 9 or greater